# How to change the background color in Google Apps Script when looping over more than one condition and using two arrays as inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried the code provided by @Cooper in another Stack Overflow thread. Here's what I did:

```
function testOfYourCode() {
  var medianResults=[11.0,45.0,11.0,12.0];
  var productType=["ProductA","ProductB","ProductC","ProductD"];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Copyof01Summary');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA=rg.getValues();

  for(let t=0;t<productType.length;t++) { 
    for(let m=0;m<medianResults.length;m++) {
      vA.forEach(function(r, i) {
        r.forEach(function(c, j) {
          if (vA[i][1]==productType[t] && vA[i][6]<=medianResults[m]) {
            cA[i][6]="#d9ead3"
          } if (vA[i][1]==productType[t] && vA[i][6]>medianResults[m]) {
            cA[i][6]="#f4cccc"
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

For some reason, and I don't know why, the color formatting is not correct for ProductB. It's correct for all other product types but not for ProductB (see screenshot below). Why does this failure occur?

[image]

### Update

I'd like to understand how to extend my code to change the background color in Google Apps Script when looping over more than one condition using two arrays as inputs.

Thanks to the help of @Cooper I managed to write this code that changes the background color based on the value in spreadsheet column 7.

```
// MY CODE THAT WORKS.
function randomcolors2d() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var cA = rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  
  vA.forEach(function(r, i) {
    r.forEach(function(c, j) {
      if (vA[i][6] <= 10) {
        cA[i][6] = "#f4cccc"
      } if (vA[i][6] > 10) {
        cA[i][6] = "#d9ead3"
      }
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

However, my problem is that this simple rule does not suit my data. I have different product types in my data and thus need to do the above but iterate through different product types and key (median) values). In my case it's 4 product types and 4 median values. But this number can change, so I need a more flexible code that accounts for that.

Without any success, I tried to use only a single forEach-loop, to integrate another for-loop either before the forEach-loop or before the if-statements or use a combination of for-loop and map-function.

Here's just one example to make it more clear what I'm intending to do:

```
// CODE THAT DOES NOT WORK.
var medianResults = [11.0, 45.0, 11.0, 12.0]; // Remember, the length of these to variable can vary!
var productType = ["ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductC", "ProductD"];
// the two arrays I'd like to use for conditioning.


function randomcolors2d() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var cA = rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA = rg.getValues();

  for (v = 0; v < productType.length; v++) { // this does not work, but how to do it?

    vA.forEach(function(r, i) {
      r.forEach(function(c, j) {
        if (vA[i][1] === productType[v] && vA[i][6] <= medianResults[v]) {
          cA[i][6] = "#f4cccc"
        } if (vA[i][1] === productType[v] && vA[i][6] > medianResults[v]) {
          cA[i][6] = "#d9ead3"
        }
      });
    });
  }
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: What are trying to achieve?  How about sharing an image with us that depicts what you are trying to achieve.  Looping through data doesn't do you any good if you don't know want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
function randomcolors2d() {
  var medianResults=[11.0,45.0,11.0,12.0];
  var productType=["ProductA","ProductB","ProductC","ProductD"];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  
  for(let t=0;t<productType.length;t++) { 
    for(let m=0;m<medianResults.length;m++) {
      vA.forEach(function(r, i) {
        r.forEach(function(c, j) {
          if (vA[i][1]==productType[t] && vA[i][6]<=medianResults[m]) {
            cA[i][6]="#f4cccc";//red
          } if (vA[i][1]==productType[t] && vA[i][6]>medianResults[m]) {
            cA[i][6]="#d9ead3";//green
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

Perhaps this is what you require:

```
function testOfYourCode() {
  var pA=[{type:"ProductA",medianResults:11.0},{type:"ProductB",medianResults:45.0},{type:"ProductC",medianResults:11.0},{type:"ProductD",medianResults:12.0}]
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Copyof01Summary');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var cA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var vA=rg.getValues();   
  pA.forEach(function(e,m) {  
    vA.forEach(function(r,i) {
      r.forEach(function(c,j) {
        if (vA[i][1]==pA[m].type && vA[i][6]<=pA[m].medianResults) {
          cA[i][6]="#d9ead3"
        } if (vA[i][1]==pA[m].type && vA[i][6]>pA[m].medianResults) {
          cA[i][6]="#f4cccc"
        }
      });
    });
  });
  rg.setBackgrounds(cA);
}
```

I was just about to give up when I realized that perhaps this is what you were trying to accomplish with those two 4 element arrays;

```
var pA=[{type:"ProductA",medianResults:11.0},{type:"ProductB",medianResults:45.0},{type:"ProductC",medianResults:11.0},{type:"ProductD",medianResults:12.0}]
```

[image]

If they're correlated to each product then indexing them through each of the products doesn't make any sense.  That's where programming and sensible analysis have to come together.

Comment: Cooper, thanks again for your help. Your code does exactly what I needed it for. As it looks like it's just a second for loop that does the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Cooper, if you don't mind taking another look at you code, I edited my question and added a screenshot of the result I get when using your code. All looks good except for one instance where your code does not yield the correct formatting. I refreshed my google apps script several times and tried it with different values, too. However, the outcome is always exactly the same. I get the wrong formatting for ProductB. Do you know why this happens? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help! I appreciate the time and effort you put in to help me. And about me not presenting the data correctly: I assumed that the error could maybe be related to the way I formatted the data in my sheet (4 blanks between each section). That's why I provided only a screenshot. I would have shared a link with you but, as stated in your profile, you don't follow a link to a Google Sheet. Once again, sorry if I caused you any inconveniences. My apologies.